# printing next element of current node of a linklist

Tags: c, data-structures

i have this code to print a linklist [1,2,3]

```
    void reverse(struct node *ptr){
          head = ptr;
          while(ptr!=NULL){

              printf("%d--->",ptr->data);

              ptr=ptr->next;
          }   
  }
```

**output :**
1-->2-->3

i am trying to print next element of ptr(current node) like

```
 void reverse(struct node *ptr){
              head = ptr;
              while(ptr!=NULL){

                  printf("%d--->",ptr->data);

                  ptr=ptr->next;
                      printf("%d--->",ptr->data);
              }   
      }
```

why is not printing **1-->2-->2-->3-->3** ?

Comment: In your second code you are doing `NULL->data` ? Do you understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to change this

```
  ptr=ptr->next;
  printf("%d--->",ptr->data);
```

to become

```
 ptr=ptr->next;
 if (NULL != ptr)
   printf("%d--->",ptr->data);
```

For the last iteration the program tries to dereference `NULL`, which leads to undefined behaviour which in turn most propably makes the program crash then.

And as `stdout` is line buffered the buffer filled with `1-->2-->2-->3` will not be flushed and printed out anymore.

---

You might have a chance to reproduce this by adding

```
flush(stdout);
```

after each call to `print()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void reverse(struct node *ptr){
              head = ptr;
              while(ptr!=NULL){

                  printf("%d--->",ptr->data);

                  ptr=ptr->next;
                  if (ptr)
                      printf("%d--->",ptr->data);
              }   
      }
```

Try this code. The problem is that ptr will be equal to `NULL` at a moment during the loop, but you're doing `printf("%d--->",ptr->data);` just after the assignation of `ptr`. It's like : `printf("%d--->",NULL->data);` which leads to an undefined behavior (you will probably get a segmentation fault).

Answer (score 1):

with the second code you will get a segmentation fault.

Because in this code

```
ptr=ptr->next;
```

where `ptr->next` is `NULL`, then `ptr` will be `NULL` and then executing

```
printf("%d--->",ptr->data);
```

with `ptr` = `NULL` will cause a segmentation fault

Comment: Don't directly say segmentation fault better to say Undefined behaviour (may be you get segmentation fault at runtime)